# Is there a clear and concise list of AWS products and their primary functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Starting with AWS seems to be a pain in the neck. I've already spent countless hours trying to squeeze out some information about what does what in their ocean of products and brand names. But there are no simple answers. First I have to read through countless pages congratulating me on choosing AWS and confirming how easily I'll be able to begin. Then I have to watch a dozen videos in which some deputy chief architect manager of whatever department explains how excited they are to see me. Yeah, thanks, but will you finally tell what does this crap do?! I don't have all the world's time.

Is there a list somewhere a clear and concise lists of AWS services and products without all the inspirational corporate bullshit, something like this one (entirely fictional):

```
Daffodil: User management service which can be embedded in your codebase.

Trainwreck: Geospatial database API.

Footsmell: Industrial automation API to control robots and drones.

Wristwatch: Thesaurus and grammar checker.
```

If there was a similar one for Google's services, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fair point, and with so many **Amazon Web Service (AWS)** services, not an easy one to sum up in a few words.

I'd say start here for a summary of the main services: https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-overview.pdf

Then I think the Tech Essentials training video from acloud.guru (with 7 day free trial) is a good video to get you going: https://acloud.guru/learn/aws-technical-essentials

---

**Google Cloud Platform** is a bit more accessible IMO, their main product page gives a brief description of the products: 
https://cloud.google.com/products/

Some context to the services: https://cloud.google.com/docs/overview/cloud-platform-services

And again acloud.guru have an introductory video for CDP: https://acloud.guru/learn/gcp-101

---

and I might as well complete the trifactor…

**Microsoft Azure** is a very worthy contender,

High level services: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/

Intro Video: https://acloud.guru/learn/intro-to-azure

Answer (score 3):

This is a slightly old list from March 2017:

**Compute**

- **Amazon EC2:** Virtual Servers in the Cloud
- **Amazon EC2 Container Service:** Run and Manage Docker Containers
- **Amazon EC2 Container Registry:** Store and Retrieve Docker Containers
- **Auto Scaling:** Automatic Elasticity
- **AWS Elastic Beanstalk:** Run and Manage Web Apps
- **Amazon LightSail:** Launch and Manage Virtual Private Servers
- **AWS Lambda:** Run your code in response to events
- **AWS Batch:** Run Batch Jobs at any Scale

**Storage**

- **Amazon S3 (Simple Storage Service):** Scalable Storage in the Cloud
- **Amazon Glacier:** Low-Cost Archive Storage in the Cloud
- **Amazon EBS (Elastic Block Store):** Block Storage for EC2
- **Amazon EFS (Elastic File System):** Managed File Storage for EC2
- **AWS Storage Gateway:** Hybrid Storage Integration

**Database**

- **Amazon RDS (Relational Database Service):** Managed Relational Database Service
- **Amazon Aurora:** High Performance Managed Relational Database
- **Amazon DynamoDB:** Managed NoSQL Database
- **Amazon Redshift:** Fast, Simple, Cost-Effective Data Warehousing
- **Amazon ElastiCache:** In-Memory Caching System

**Migration**

- **Snowball:** Petabyte-scale Data Transport
- **AWS Application Discovery Service:** Discover On-Premises Apps
- **AWS Database Migration Service:** Migrate Databases with Minimal Downtime
- **AWS Server Migration Service:** Migrate On-Premises Servers to AWS

**Networking & Content Delivery**

- **Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC):** Isolate Cloud Resources
- **AWS Direct Connect:** Dedicated Network Connection to AWS
- **Amazon Route 53:** Scalable Domain Name Service
- **Elastic Load Balancing:** High Scale Load Balancing
- **Amazon CloudFront:** Global Content Delivery Network

**Developer Tools**

- **AWS CodeCommit:** Store Code in Private Git Repositories
- **AWS CodeBuild:** Build and Test Code
- **AWS CodeDeploy:** Automate Code Deployment
- **AWS CodePipeline:** Release Software using Continuous Delivery
- **AWS X-Ray:** Analyze and Debug Your Applications
- **AWS Command-Line Interface:** Unified Tool to Manage AWS Services

**Management Tools**

- **AWS CloudFormation:** Create and Manage Resources with Templates
- **AWS Service Catalog:** Create and Use Standardized Products
- **Amazon CloudWatch:** Monitor Resources and Applications
- **AWS CloudTrail:** Track User Activity and API Usage
- **AWS Config:** Track Resource Inventory and Changes
- **AWS OpsWorks:** Automate Operations with Chef
- **Amazon EC2 Systems Manager:** Configure EC2 Instances and On-Premises Servers
- **AWS Trusted Advisor:** Optimize Performance and Security
- **AWS Personal Health Dashboard:** Personalized View of AWS service health

**Security, Identity & Compliance**

- **AWS Identity & Access Management (IAM):** Manage User Access and Encryption Keys
- **AWS Organizations:** Policy-Based Management for Multiple AWS Accounts
- **AWS Directory Service:** Host and Manage Active Directory
- **AWS Cloud Directory:** Create flexible cloud-native directories
- **AWS Key Management Service (KMS):** Creation and Control of Encryption Keys
- **AWS CloudHSM:** Hardware-based Key Storage
- **AWS Certificate Manager:** Provision and Deploy SSL/TLS Certificates
- **Amazon Inspector:** Analyze Application Security
- **AWS Shield:** Managed DDoS Protection
- **AWS Web Application Firewall (WAF):** Filter Malicious Web Traffic

**Analytics**

- **Amazon Athena:** Query Data in S3 using SQL
- **Amazon EMR:** Hosted Hadoop Framework
- **Amazon CloudSearch:** Managed Search Service
- **Amazon Elasticsearch Service:** Run and Scale Elasticsearch Clusters
- **Amazon Kinesis:** Work with Real-Time Streaming Data
- **Amazon QuickSight:** Fast Business Analytics Service
- **AWS Data Pipeline:** Orchestration Service for periodic Data-Driven Workflows
- **AWS Glue:** Prepare and Load Data

**Artificial Intelligence**

- **Amazon Machine Learning:** Machine Learning for Developers
- **Amazon Polly:** Turn Text into Lifelike Speech
- **Amazon Rekognition:** Search and Analyze Images
- **Amazon Lex:** Build Voice and Text Chatbots

**Mobile Services**

- **Amazon Cognito:** User Identity and App Data Synchronization
- **AWS Device Farm:** Test Mobile Apps on Real Devices in the Cloud
- **AWS Mobile Hub & Mobile SDK:** Build, Test and Monitor Mobile Apps

**Application Services**

- **Amazon API Gateway:** Build, Deploy and Manage APIs
- **AWS Step Functions:** Coordinate Distributed Applications
- **Amazon Elastic Transcoder:** Easy-to-Use Scalable Media Transcoding

**Messaging**

- **Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS):** Message Queue Service
- **Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS):** Push Notification Service
- **Amazon Simple Email Service (SES):** Email Sending and Receiving Service
- **Amazon Pinpoint:** Push Notifications for Mobile Apps

**Business Productivity**

- **Amazon Chime:** Frustration-free meetings, video calls and chats
- **Amazon WorkDocs:** Enterprise Storage and Sharing Service
- **Amazon WorkMail:** Managed Business Email and Calendaring

**Desktop & App Streaming**

- **Amazon WorkSpaces:** Desktop Computing Service
- **Amazon AppStream 2.0:** Stream desktop applications to a browser

**Internet of Things**

- **AWS IoT Platform:** Connect Devices to the Cloud
- **AWS Greengrass:** Local Compute, Messaging, Sync for Devices
- **AWS IoT Button:** Cloud Programmable Dash Button

**Game Dev**

- **Amazon GameLift:** Dedicated Game Server Hosting
- **Amazon Lumberyard:** Free Cross-Platform 3D game engine

There's even more these days!

Comment: could you help me answer the question linked below? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226785/how-do-i-store-aws-pinpoint-messages-to-rds

Answer (score 1):

If you want one liners like you mentioned in your questions then [click here](https://aws.amazon.com/products/)

On that page click on the category of the service and it will list out services in that category and one line description.

E.g. Click 'Compute' to see the list of provided compute services, click 'Storage' to list if provided storage services and so on

If you want somewhat detailed explanation, [click here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-technical-content/latest/aws-overview/amazon-web-services-cloud-platform.html)

Here also services are grouped in categories, and you click on one of categories and you get to see the services (along with some brief explanation about each of the service) within that category

Answer (score 0):

The documentation page of each product gives explanation in a simple way. Moreover, if you read the FAQ that explains things from scratch.